# Rails3 ajax updating data for use in google maps

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

I have an ajax-form to send the points and with these points I find the shortest path between these two points.

All this works without ajax, just send the data to the server and re-render the page and all that stuff, **but I need this work with ajax**

**The problem is** I can't send/upload the data(json) I generate in the server(controller + model) to the client(view)

I'm doing this (1) and how I said it works whitout ajax

(1)

```
# views/places/finder.html.erb    
<%= form_tag({controller: "places", action: "found"}, remote: true) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :lon_s %> # 
    <%= hidden_field_tag :lat_s %> # these fields are updated automatically
    <%= hidden_field_tag :lon_t %> # with clicks the user do on the map 
    <%= hidden_field_tag :lat_t %> #

    <%= submit_tag "Buscar ruta", id: 'buscar_ruta' %>
<% end -%>

#places_controller.rb
def found
    res = Way.path_cost_from(params[:lon_s].to_f, params[:lat_s].to_f, 
                             params[:lon_t].to_f, params[:lat_t].to_f)
    @costo = res[:cost]
    gon.poly = Way.get_way(res[:edges])
    @path = Way.get_way(res[:edges])
end

#views/places/found.js.coffee
console.log <%= @costo %> #this show the cost in the console, it works.
console.log <%= gon.poly %> #undefined local variable or method `gon'
console.log <%= @path %> #Error: Parse error on line 3: Unexpected ':'
```

Before in the ajax-less version I use the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon), to pass the points needed for the Google maps API need to show/build a polyline.

```
#assets/javascripsts/places.js.coffee
if gon.poly?
  poly = gon.poly
  MAP.addPolyline poly
```

**poly** is an object I build in a json format.

```
each do |point|
    path << { lon: unprojected_point.x, lat: unprojected_point.y }
end
return path
```

If you like you can see my project in my github account https://github.com/figuedmundo/final

I was looking for examples to do this but the only examples I found was to render some html code for update the page (the normal ajax), but the google maps api is just javascript.

---

**Solution**

The idea of my code might not be the optimal but it works and in the end that's what the client want.

The problem was that the variable **@path** that was passed to the view automatically was scaped so the json object wasn't readable. **html_safe** do the trick

```
console.log <%=  @path.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use 
<%= f.submit_tag "Buscar ruta", id: 'buscar_ruta' %>
Instead of 
<%= submit_tag "Buscar ruta", id: 'buscar_ruta' %

Comment: actually if I put the f. it shows me an error `undefined method 'submit_tag' for nil:NilClass` becouse for the form_tag helper there is not necesary the `|f|` after the  `do`, that was my mistake.